# Mostrar mensagem de sucesso sem sair da página

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Eu tenho um formulário que envia alguns dados para o banco de dados e faz o upload para um FTP, a parte do banco tem um `if` que retorna o erro numa variável e mostra o erro no próprio formulário. Mas minha dúvida é como eu faço isso para outro tipo de erro ? Segue o código abaixo:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (versao, revisao, data) VALUES 
('".$versao."', '".$revisao."', '".$data."')";
$resultado= mysqli_query($conn, $query);


if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Versão e Revisão cadastrada com sucesso!</div>";
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Erro ao cadastrar ao cadastrar Versão e Revisão!</div>";
}
```

Esse é o exemplo que armazena numa variável e mostra em uma parte do formulário HTML.

```
<div class="container">

<?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
        echo $_SESSION['msg'];
        unset($_SESSION['msg']);
    }
?>
```

Como eu poderia fazer para essa mensagem eu conseguir exibir na página do formulário ao invés de ir para outra página mostrar a mensagem ?

```
if ( @ftp_put( $conexao_ftp, $destino, $arquivo_temp, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
// Se for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
    echo '<br> <p class="alert alert-success d-flex justify-content-center"> Arquivo enviado com sucesso! </p>';

} else {
// Se não for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
    echo '<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Erro ao enviar arquivo! </p>';
}
```

[image: Como nesse exemplo que mostra a mensagem acima do formulário]

Comment: Em php não da pra ser feito, vai ter que usar ajax.

Comment: do jeito que tem ali no exemplo que tem `$_SESSION['msg'] = `, não teria como fazer algo parecido com isso ? Tentei fazer igual esse ali e não deu certo. Ou nesse caso ali é por está dentro de uma sessão ?

Comment: Não tem como fazer isso. Só com php você não consegui alterar o conteúdo da página, tu precisa usar javascript, com ajax, sugiro que você estude isso melhor pra pode implementar. Dei uma rápida pesquisa e isso [aqui](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-um-cadastro-com-php-ajax-e-jquery/28046) pode ajudar, é um tutorial que cria um cadastro em php com ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
session_start();

// Verifica se o "dados" está configurado, se sim significa q o form foi submetido(enviado)
if ( isset($_POST['dados']) ) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (versao, revisao, data) VALUES ('".$versao."', '".$revisao."', '".$data."')";

    $resultado= mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)) {
      $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Versão e Revisão cadastrada    com sucesso!</div>";
    }else{
      $_SESSION['msg'] = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>Erro ao cadastrar ao cadastrar  Versão e Revisão!</div>";
    }

    if ( @ftp_put( $conexao_ftp, $destino, $arquivo_temp, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
      // Se for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
      $_SESSION['msg2'] = '<br> <p class="alert alert-success d-flex justify-content-center"> Arquivo enviado com sucesso! </p>';

    } else {
        // Se não for enviado, mostra essa mensagem
       $_SESSION['msg2'] = '<br> <p class="alert alert-danger d-flex justify-content-center"> Erro ao enviar arquivo! </p>';
    }

} // fim do if

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Seu form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <?php

            // Mostra a msg q está na variável global $_SESSION
            if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
                echo $_SESSION['msg'];
                unset($_SESSION['msg']);
            }

            if(isset($_SESSION['msg2'])){
                echo $_SESSION['msg2'];
                unset($_SESSION['msg2']);
            }

        ?>

        <!-- Deixe o action vazio para que os dados sejam enviados para propria página  -->
        <!-- Isso resolve o seu problema de sair da página -->
        <form method="post" action="">

            <!-- crie um input do tipo hidden(oculto) para sinalizar que os dados do form foram enviados -->
            <input type="hidden" name="dados">


        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aahh acho que entendi, então essa variável $_SESSION é na verdade uma função do php que funciona dentro de uma sessão iniciada ?

Comment: Ela é uma 'superglobal', ou global automática, variável. Isto simplesmente significa que ela está disponível em todos escopos pelo script.

Comment: Usando esse método, irá me retornar a mensagem no próprio form, mas ele irá redirecionar para uma página em branco que seria meu php, ai quando eu voltar para a página do form, aparece as mensagem, o único de continuar na página seria usando ajax para enviar os dados como o amigo acima disse, certo ?

Comment: Você pode sim mandar os dados para outro arquivo .php
e depois redirecionar para a página do form novamente com:
    echo "<script> location.href = 'seuform.php'; </script>";

Answer (score 2):

Como o php só roda do lado do servidor, a informação chega no servidor, ele te dá um retorno, e a página é carregada.
Você vai precisar utilizar ajax meu amigo.

Use o método de envio (Estou utilizando o jquery nesse caso):

```
<script>
function enviarDados(){
    $.ajax({
     method: "POST",
     url: "seuarquivo.php",
     data: { versao: $("#versao").val(), revisao: $("#revisao").val(), data: $("#data").val() },
     function(msg){
       $("#resultado").html(msg);
       // #resultado é um id de um elemento de texto, como <p> ou <span>
       //quando você der echo na outra página, ele virá como parâmetro para essa função aqui.
     }
    });
  }
</script>
```

No `data` você passa um objeto com chave e valor das variáveis que vão ser enviadas.

No seu `form` você pode colocar um evento de click no botão, algo como:

```
<button onclick="enviarDados();">Salvar</button>
```

O seu php pode ficar como está, você só vai atribuir a variáveis os dados que vão chegar via post. Você vai precisar de uma estratégia para pegar os dados.
Normalmente, pego o `.val()` do `input` e coloco em uma variável, `versao` por exemplo. Lembre-se de colocar o echo em seu php.

Existem outros métodos que utilizam ajax, como o $.post. Leia mais [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp)

Comment: Fazendo com AJAX, a única coisa que vai atualizar na página será minha mensagem de sucesso ou erro ? E como eu faria para mostrar a mensagem ?

Comment: Editei com a resposta

Comment: Vale lembrar que $.ajax é uma função da biblioteca jquery, então se tu já não tiver importado ela pro projeto, tu vai ter que fazer.

Comment: Ao invés de eu colocar o `action=teste.php`, eu deixaria em branco e a action seria feito pelo onclick do button ?

Comment: Isso, vai precisar do jquery, ou mudar a função para o getElementById

Comment: Você vai precisar tirar o action, e recomendo que troque o input de type submit para um <button> mesmo.

Comment: Então, na página do form coloquei esse código que você me passou, ai no meu php dexei desse jeito (http://prntscr.com/li8fvm), a página aparece que ta fazendo a conexão segura e tal, mas ela limpa os campos do form e não envia nada, tenho que mudar mais alguma coisa no php ?